# Javascript : Encode byte [ ] array to base64

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, arrays

I have a simple question: how to encode a `byte [ ]` to `base64` format?

I have the following code:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1("payLoad");
    document.writeln(hash);
    hash = hash.toString();

    var bytes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < hash.length; ++i)
{
    bytes.push(hash.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

Now I would like to encode `bytes[ ]` to `base64` format. Is there a library to do that?

I will appreciate your help!

Comment: Browsers have built-in `atob()` and `btoa()` functions

Comment: Thanks, but they don't seem to work with byte[ ] .

Answer (score 0):

`btoa` and `atob` work with strings, which they treat as arrays of bytes, so to use these two functions, you should first convert your array of integers (provided they fall in the range 0-255) into a string.

something that worked here for me was these two simple functions:

```js
  b64encode = function(x) { 
    return btoa(x.map(function(v){return String.fromCharCode(v)}).join(''))
  };
  b64decode = function(x) {
    return atob(x).split('').map(function(v) {return v.codePointAt(0)});
  };
```

I'm sure you can write them in better style.

in your case though your data was already in the correct format, before you converted it to a 32 bit integer array.  the fact that you call the array `bytes` is only misleading you I think.  after that, `btoa` converted the bloated array, instead of the array of bytes you had in your `hash`.